# PL/SQL - UTL_FILE physical location of the file

Tags: oracle, plsql, utl-file

I want to use `UTL_FILE` pkg to read data from a `csv` file, I already have the code for it, but where exactly I should place the file?

I know that I need to give the path with the `UTL_FILE.FOPEN`, and I can also create a directory, but I can't find it after creating, so I can't put the file into that directory.

Could you please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: You really do not want UTL_FILE to load a .csv. Use SQL*Loader or define an External Table for this purpose. With utl_file, you have to responsibility to parse file record into fields to columns. Either SQL*Loader and an External table do that for you. With an external table the file location must be on the db server  (or a network share) not on your local machine. See your DBA.  With SQL*Loader the file may be stored locally, or a network share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Usually**:

- `SYS`user creates directory (Oracle object which points to a filesystem directory which resides **on the database server**
- `SYS` also grants `read` and/or `read` privileges on that directory (Oracle object) to user(s) who will be using it, i.e. storing files in there
- in order to be able to manipulate files on the operating system level, DBA grants you appropriate privileges on that filesystem directory. Otherwise, you won't be able to put files in there (such as your CSV file) nor get files you created using `UTL_FILE`

When everything of above is done, then you'll be able to fully use the directory.

Therefore: if you're not a DBA, you're probably in vain "creating directory" (as you said) because - if you were, you'd already know how it works. I suggest you talk to your DBA.